# Ways to keep an Array unchanged when pasting them as argument to function Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of objects A

And I have 2 different drawing functions which change A completely in their own ways. 
I would like to keep A unchanged. Is there best practices how to do it? My current solution is somehow feels unnatural:

```
var A;//Should stay the same always

drawGraphX(A){
//Modifying A here to draw but I would like the original A to stay the same
B=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A));
//So I do it with B
}

drawGraphY(A){
//Modifying A here to draw
B=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A));
//So I do it with B
}
```

Comment: An example of A would be nice.

Comment: Can you provide an example which can be executed stating the problem ?

Comment: It looks like you know the solution already, I don't see why `A=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A));` wouldn't work? After you cloned `A`, do whatever you want with the clones.

Comment: I think youve got a bigger problem, and that is - why should a function which draws a graph be changing the input *at all*? This seems like an XY Problem to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the *real* answer here is that you shouldn't be changing the data inside your function *at all*!

Lets imagine that `A` is an array of x/y points to be used for a chart

```
var A = [{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:3}];
```

And your function just wants the `x` - are you doing this:

```
function drawGraphX(A){
   for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++)
      A[i] = A[i].x; 

   // now draw the graph
}
```

In the above example, yes,, you will be changing the source of A as you've just passed a reference in to the function and updated the elements of that referenced array. This is bad practice, what you should be doing is this:

```
function drawGraphX(A){
   var data = A.map(function(e){
       return e.x;
   });

   // data is an array of just the x values
}
```

Comment: This literally doubles all work when you actually do want to mutate the Array. Now you have to push an object instead of just a number.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard I literally have no idea what you just said.

Comment: You now have an array of objects instead of an array of numbers. And each object has two parts. What if I want to add more numbers to my array later? Instead of `a.push(6)` I have to write `a.push({x:6, y:6})`. It just seems like wasted effort.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard I think you've fundamentally misunderstood my answer. My point was that you shouldnt be changing the data within a method which draws a graph. You should be using a copy of it (much like your answer says). If you had a new point to add (value:6) that would be `data.push(6);`

Comment: I understand now. You're quite right. I misunderstood your example 'A' variable, because 'A' was used in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `drawGraphX(A.slice())` [slice returns copy of array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) if shallow copy is fine for you and it is just about array itself, however remember that you are in fact not cloning objects so

```
var A = [{test:'foo', test2:'bar'}, {test:'foo1', test2:'bar1'}];
var B = A.slice();
A[0].test = 'foobar';
console.log(B[0].test);
```

will return you `"foobar"`

so it is fine if you mutate array itself but not elements (note that the same comment goes to `Array.from(A)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use the `Array.from()` method, to pass a new array into your function. So, when you call `drawGraphX(A)`, instead call `drawGraphX(Array.from(A))`. This will create a new Array of the same data you had in 'A'. Easy Peasy.

```
var b = Array.from(A);
drawGraphX(b);
```

or

```
drawGraphX(Array.from(A));
```

Edit: As netRat and Jonasw pointed out. This will make a new array, but it keeps references to the individual objects. Meaning that while mutating the Array will not change the source array, changing any of the objects shared by the two arrays will change the source material. I.E.:

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = Array.from(a);
b[0] = b[0]++;
console.log(a); // will result [2,2];
```

while

```
b.push[3];
console.log(a); // will result [1,2]
console.log(b); // will result [1,2,3];
```

Proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/5hLjajc0/1/

Answer (score -1):

The more elegant solution would be sth like a switch, that if an objs is undefined, take a parents one:

```
function switch(obj,prot){
 return function(keys,val){
  keys= keys.split(".");
  var el=obj;
  var par;
  for(key of keys){
    par=el
    el=el[key];        
  }
  if(el==undefined){
          var el=prot;
          var par;
          for(key of keys){
           par=el
           el=el[key];        
           }
   }
  if(value){
    par[keys[keys.length]]=value;
  }
  return el;
  };}
```

Use like this:

```
prot=[0,1,3];//unchangeable
obj=[,5,];
callfunc(switch(obj,prot));
function callfunc(el){
//read
el("0");//0
el("1");//5
el("2");//3
//write
el("0", 12);//do not override prot
//also with multidim stuff:
el("0.a");
}
```

Its mainly an improved version of prototypes:

```
var obj={
 0:function(){
  alert("original prototype");
 },
 1:5
 }

 callfunc(Object.create(obj));//...
 callfunc(Object.create(obj));//...
```

This will allow you to access the prototypes props, wich cant be overriden that easily:

```
function callfunc(arg){
  arg[0]();//works as expected
  arg[0]=function(){
    alert("hi");
  }
  arg[0]();//hi
  }
```

This doesnt override the prototype, it extends the arg...
To override you can still do

```
arg.prototype[0]=function(){
 alert("hi prototype");
};
```

Comment: Why would you use such a convoluted solution when you could just pass in a copy in the first place? What's the benefit?

Comment: @EvSunWoodard big objects+ much copies -> much data. Wouldnt it be better to just store as much as needed?

Comment: Copies of arrays have such a small amount of data that the effect or performance is negligible. Making your code unreadable should not be done for a slight efficiency boost in javascript, because you are virtually guaranteed that the end user will be using your code in an environment with enough data throughput to cover it. As long as you aren't making O(n^2) code, it really is irrelevant. If we were writing in C, or for a low memory system I would agree with you.

Comment: @EvSunWoodward: well, question still answered . the OP can decide if he wantslow memory consumption or a bit better performance + readability.

Comment: This **is** a *really* convoluted solution to the problem though.